# How can I read a text from a file and insert the values in a Struct using C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to read a file and put the values in a Struct to sort then, but my code isn't working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
struct person
{
    char Nome[50];
    int Idade;
    double Altura;
};


int main ()
{
    FILE *infile;
    struct person input;
     
    infile = fopen ("pessoas.txt", "r");
    if (infile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file\n");
        exit (1);
    }
     
    while(fread(&input, sizeof(struct person), 1, infile))
        printf ("Nome = %s Idade = %d Altura = %f\n", input.Nome,
        input.Idade, input.Altura);
 
    // close file
    fclose (infile);
 
    return 0;
}
```

My file is:

Maria

15

1.6

Joao

21

1.8

Abel

23

1.7

Joana

40

1.6

Comment: `fread(&input, sizeof(struct person), 1, infile)` will read a `struct person` record from the file _if_ the file is created _binary_ (with a similar `fwrite`). Your file is a plain text file by the looks of it. Use `fgets` and read line by line and convert the `int` and `double`

Comment: Something like that?     `while(fgets(S1, 100, infile))
        printf("%s",S1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fscanf()` to read file & populate the structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
struct person
{
    char Nome[50];
    int Idade;
    double Altura;
};


int main ()
{
    FILE *infile;
    struct person input;
     
    infile = fopen ("pessoas.txt", "r");
    if (infile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    while(3 != fscanf(infile, "%49s %d %lf", input.Nome, &input.Idade, &input.Altura))
        printf ("Nome = %s Idade = %d Altura = %lf\n", input.Nome, input.Idade, input.Altura);
 
    // close file
    fclose (infile);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can I compare the double value from the Struct?

Comment: What are you trying to do by comparing those values?

Comment: Yes, I want to compare the 1.6, 1.8, 1.7, 1.6, and Sort the Name and Age by that

Comment: @TedLyngmo Right, I overlooked that bit. Cheers.

Comment: You may want to consider using `%49s` instead of `%s` when using `fscanf`. Otherwise, a buffer overflow is possible.